# How to check and return true if json object key is having all same values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, object, key

I have the following sample JSON object:

```
var data = [ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Abc",
  "age" : 30,
  "married" : true,
  "city": "ABC"
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Def",
  "age" : 25,
  "married" : true,
  "city": "ABC"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Pqr",
  "age" : 28,
  "married" : false,
  "city": "ABC"
}, {
  "id" : 4,
  "name" : "Xyz",
  "age" : 40,
  "married" : true,
  "city": "ABC"
} ];
```

I want to return `true` and store it in a variable if all `city` key values are `ABC` only, or else it should return `false`(i.e if one of `city` key values is not `ABC`)  from the given `JSON` object. Can anyone please let me know on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to test if something is true for every element of an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const data = [ { "id" : 1, "name" : "Abc", "age" : 30, "married" : true, "city": "ABC" }, { "id" : 2, "name" : "Def", "age" : 25, "married" : true, "city": "ABC" }, { "id" : 3, "name" : "Pqr", "age" : 28, "married" : false, "city": "ABC" }, { "id" : 4, "name" : "Xyz", "age" : 40, "married" : true, "city": "ABC" } ];

const valid = data.every(({ city }) => city === 'ABC');

console.log(valid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Three possible ways of achieving this:

- Using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- Using [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let data = [{id:1,name:"Abc",age:30,married:!0,city:"ABC"},{id:2,name:"Def",age:25,married:!0,city:"ABC"},{id:3,name:"Pqr",age:28,married:!1,city:"ABC"},{id:4,name:"Xyz",age:40,married:!0,city:"ABC"}];

console.log(data.every(({ city }) => city === "ABC"));
console.log(!data.some(({ city }) => city !== "ABC"));
console.log(!data.filter(({ city }) => city !== "ABC").length);
```

Comment: @Guna Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your three solution ways, all are solving my query, Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

simply :

```
data.filter(x => x.city === 'ABC')
```

Please do a more detailed search about the problem before opening a topic.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it will filters only ABC values, it will not check every key. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.some((el) => el.city !== "ABC")
```